# Export metrics from prometheus to postgres (RDS)

Tags: postgresql, prometheus

I've been exploring for a possible solution that would help to export certain metrics from prometheus to postgres for analytical purpose.

I came across the [prometheus-postgres-adapter](https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter), unfortunately it will store the metrics in its own postgres, i.e a statefulset in k8s and doesn't support an external postgres like AWS RDS. There's an open issue for this: https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter/issues/10

Is there any other alternatives? or should we write our own adapter?